# ¿problema con IndexOutOfRangeException en c#?

Tags: c#

Trato de hacer un split que me permita dividir datos que un puerto serial me envía pero al momento de leerlos , la aplicación se detiene y me manda error en la matriz este es parte del código que estoy usando para hacer el split quisiera saber que me puede estar generando el problema.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void DelegadoAcceso(String accion);
        private String strBufferIn;
        private String strbufferOut;




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AccesoForm(String accion)
        {

            //----------------------------------Aqui llegan los datos
            strBufferIn = accion;
            TxtDatosRecibidos.Text = strBufferIn;
            string input = TxtDatosRecibidos.Text;
            string[] sp;
            sp = input.Split(',');
            textBox1.Text = sp[0];
            textBox2.Text = sp[1];
            textBox3.Text = sp[2];
            textBox4.Text = sp[3];
            textBox5.Text = sp[4];
            textBox6.Text = sp[5];
            textBox7.Text = sp[6];
            textBox8.Text = sp[7];
```

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]. De todo este codigo, donde esta tu problema? tenes que ser mas puntual con tu error.

Comment: //----------------------------------Aqui llegan los datos
            strBufferIn = accion;
            TxtDatosRecibidos.Text = strBufferIn;
            string input = TxtDatosRecibidos.Text;
            string[] sp;
            sp = input.Split(',');
            textBox1.Text = sp[0];
            textBox2.Text = sp[1];
            textBox3.Text = sp[2];
            textBox4.Text = sp[3];
            textBox5.Text = sp[4];
            textBox6.Text = sp[5];
            textBox7.Text = sp[6];
            textBox8.Text = sp[7];
 esta es la parte de mi problema la señale

Comment: Estas seguro de que en `TxtDatosRecibidos.Text` tienes 8 partes separadas por comas? Lo primero que debes analizar es que estas recibiendo por el puerto serie, es posible que no estes recibiendo todos los datos que esperas de una sola vez

Comment: se supone que tiene 8 partes separadas las conte , desde arduino antes de mandarlas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te está dando significa que estas intentando obtener un dato de una posicion de un `array[]` en la cual no existen datos, es decir, si suponemos que tu array tiene 6 posiciones con datos (del 0 al 5) y tu intentas obtener los dstos de la posición 6 te da el error [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) porque te has pasado del rango del array.

En el código que estás utilizando deberías comprobar, antes de asignar los datos a los `TextBox`, que lo que vas a intentar introducir en ellos existe, por ejemplo de ésta forma:

```
sp = input.Split(',');
if (sp.Length > 0)
    textBox1.Text = sp[0];

if (sp.Length > 1)
    textBox2.Text = sp[1];

if (sp.Length > 2)
    textBox3.Text = sp[2];
```

Comment: Viejo eres un maldito dios muchas gracias , se soluciono , espero no toparme con otro error